# Images are not displayed in the Apple Mail desktop client

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email, email-client

Could you please help me solve a problem. The Apple desktop mail client that my customer uses doesn't displaying images in emails.

While testing, my Gmail and Apple desktop mail client display images. The customer only has it working in Gmail.

What could be the reason that the user's Apple desktop mail client is not displaying images? How can this be fixed?

[image: Result]

- All images are stored on Google drive and are available to everyone via a link. The links are used correctly and work.
- Templates are used and sent via Postmark.
- Here's an example of using an image in HTML:
  `<img alt="Logo" height="auto" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1fwi_0j2qSZOGZ2Sk91dXMWmqKCYIVti5" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; display: block; outline: none; height: auto; width: 100%;" title="logo" width="90">`

Comment: I don't think Google drive was ever created to support that sort of use case. It's usually used as an internal thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue with Apple Mail and there are no sure-fire answers. The following steps worked in one case where my co-worker used Chrome as default browser on an M1 Macbook.

1. Empty Chrome cache
2. Uncheck Chrome option `Preload pages for faster browsing`
3. Restart Mac (and cross fingers or `<favourite defeat jinx gesture>`)

A possible justification for this fix is that Mac Mail is using the browser rendering engine and cache for HTML mail. This makes sense to me, as rendering HTML is not the mail client's main job, and would involve a lot of duplicate work and constant updates.